# How to use fasttext vectors in a tensorflow embedding layer?

Tags: tensorflow

I just struggle to find out how I can use Fasttext wordvectors for OOV words in  a keras/tensorflow embedding layer. There is nothing out there. Maybe someone has thought of that too and has some hints for me?

The way via word embedding look up works via indices like
tf.nn.embedding_lookup(word_embeddings, x)

And you could have an index for one OOV. But how can I assign a specific vector (from a different and custom source like fasttext) at runtime?

I imagine a function which can customly assign a vector to the UNK index for a OOV word.

Related to that:

[Assign custom word vector to UNK token during prediction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045468/assign-custom-word-vector-to-unk-token-during-prediction)

[Using subword information in OOV token from fasttext in word embedding layer (keras/tensorflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043487/using-subword-information-in-oov-token-from-fasttext-in-word-embedding-layer-ke)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the embedding lookup \ computation outside of tensorflow, and use the embedded text as input to the model (so the input wont be a sequence of word indices, but a sequence of vectors)